# 2000 rows limit in Salesforce report while connecting to PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, salesforce

I had connected Salesforce report with PowerBi and only 2000 rows got fetched. I had connected to Salesforce object as well, but there are some fields missing which can not be added by the organization. Is there any other way to connect to Salesforce report and fetch all the data to PowerBi?

I wanted to make the report live through connecting to Salesforce report. But the rows are more than 2000 in the report.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation:

> The number of rows you can access in Salesforce Reports is limited by Salesforce to 2000 rows. As a workaround for this issue, you can use the [Salesforce Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/salesforce-objects) connector in Power BI Desktop to retrieve all the rows from individual tables and recreate reports you’d like. The Object connector doesn’t have the 2000-row limit.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/salesforce-reports#known-issues-and-limitations